# Contar o total de páginas de um PDF usando PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde a todos,

Desenvolvi um código que retorna como saída o total de páginas de PDFs de um diretório específico.

Até consegui ler o total de páginas, porém ele para de executar após a leitura do primeiro PDF do diretório.

Uma obs: Minha estrutura de pastas está da seguinte forma:

```
root
| _In
   |'anos'
      |'meses'
         |'Arqs'
```

**Se alguém puder me ajudar, super agradeço!**

Segue o código abaixo:

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$_DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$rootPath = dirname(__FILE__);
$_In = $rootPath.$_DS.'_In';

if(isset($_POST['btn'])){ 

    for($ano = 1977; $ano <=2019; $ano++){ $subInY = $_In.$_DS.$ano; $Out = $_Out.$_DS.$ano;

        if(is_dir($subInY)){ /*echo "<br>".$subInY.'<br>';*/ } 

        for($mes = 1; $mes <= 12; $mes++){ $subInM = $subInY.$_DS.$mes; $subOutM = $Out.$_DS.$mes; 

            if(is_dir($subInM)){ /*echo $subInM.'<br>';*/ 

                $in = new DirectoryIterator($_In);
                $siy = new DirectoryIterator($subInY);

                foreach($in as $p1){ if($p1->isDot()) continue; foreach($siy as $p2){ if($p2->isDot()) continue; } }    


                $arq2 = glob("{$subInM}\*.pdf");

                foreach($arq2 as $file){ 


                    echo '<br>'.$file.'<br>';


                    // ======================= ParserPDF

                    $parser  = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
                    $pdf     = $parser->parseFile($file);

                    $details = $pdf->getDetails();                  
                    foreach ($details as $property => $value) { 
                        if (is_array($value)) {
                            $value = implode(', ', $value); }

                    if($property == "Pages"){  
                        echo "<br>" . $property . ' => ' . $value . "<br>\n";}

                    }

                    set_time_limit(3000);   

                    // ========================     

                }           
    } } }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

eu uso esta função aqui:

```
function count_pages($pdfname) {
  $pdftext = file_get_contents($pdfname);
  $num = preg_match_all("/\/Page\W/", $pdftext, $dummy);
  return $num;
}
```

Comment: Jasar, essa variável $dummy, seria o que?

Comment: Desculpa, mas não consegui visualizar como inserir no meu código.

Comment: sabe onde vc carrega o pdf como arquivo ? `$file`
pega o endereço e o nome do arquivo completo e usaa essa função q passei

Comment: Jasar, essa variável $dummy, seria o que?

Comment: de acordo com a documentação é onde ele joga os matches do que achou no regex
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php

mas não precisamos dos resultados. Somente conta-los

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o Imagick, ja me deparei com esa duvida uma vez

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->pingImage('name_of_pdf_file.pdf');
$pagesCount = $im->getNumberImages();
```